# Typescript: Pass an extra parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript1.7

I was trying the below code from the [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#14-structural-subtyping)

```
interface Point {  
    x: number;  
    y: number;  
}

function getX(p: Point) {  
    return p.x;  
}

class CPoint {  
    x: number;  
    y: number;  
    constructor(x: number,  y: number) {  
        this.x = x;  
        this.y = y;  
    }  
}

getX(new CPoint(0, 0));  // Ok, fields match

getX({ x: 0, y: 0, color: "red" });  // Extra fields Ok

getX({ x: 0 });  // Error: supplied parameter does not match
```

As per the code comment says below line should be ok.

```
getX({ x: 0, y: 0, color: "red" });  // Extra fields Ok
```

**But i am getting error as below:**

> error TS2345: Argument of type '{ x: number; y: number; color: string;
>   }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Point'.   Object literal
>   may only specify known properties, and 'color' does not exist in type
>   'Point'

**But the below code works well which i re-wrote in which i made params as optional:**

```
interface Point {  
    x: number;  
    y?: number; 
    color?: string; 
}

function getX(p: Point) {  
    return p.x;  
}

class CPoint {  
    x: number;  
    y: number;  
    constructor(x: number,  y: number) {  
        this.x = x;  
        this.y = y;  
    }  
}

getX(new CPoint(0, 0));  // Ok, fields match

getX({ x: 0, y: 0, color: "red" });  // Extra fields Ok

getX({ x: 0 });  // Error: supplied parameter does not match
```

Please can somebody help me out if the documentation is wrong or am i missing something here

**FYI i am using:**

- Typescript v1.7.5
- Visual studio code

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: On the [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground) your code works as expected. This can be an issue with the editor

Comment: I just tried it out on my computer with visual studio code and i don't have any error. I have typescript version 1.7.5

Comment: oh is it.. can you share the VS version please?

Comment: i have added the screnshot.

Comment: Version 0.10.6 Shell 0.3435 Node 4.1.1  [image](http://postimg.org/image/z2msdjyzn/)

Comment: can you try the documentation code.. from the screenshot i could see you have tried the code i re-wrote. Sample code provided in documentation is throwing the error .Can be seen in the first part of my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102901/discussion-between-raulucco-and-nirus).

Comment: I think you misdefined the initial problem. You say adding extra properties to an object literal is OK, yet the error message is stating _exactly_ that it's not OK. However, I see no reason for this feature to exist (besides what some might consider best practices), as an interface (more precisely, its implementation) should be a _requirement_ for an object, and not a _limiting factor_. The documentation is either outdated or wrong (or there's a factor I'm not seeing) - I try to add additional properties to an objet literal, and I get the same error (and I've been getting it since ever).

Comment: Long story short: a Typescript interface works differently on object literals. Instead of acting as an implementation definition listing _required_ members, it instead describes an _exact_ object signature.

Comment: @JohnWhite Well i don't see the above statement anywhere in the Doc, apparently documentation says its OK to pass an extra parameter which is not defined in the interface, but trying out the same sample code on the VS code throws an error and i find documentation is either misleading or might require an update.

Comment: Then I'd say the documentation is misleading. I've always got this error ever since I started diving into Typescript.

Comment: @JohnWhite Thank you. I have filed an issue on github on this.

Comment: Object freshness : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/freshness.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is out of date. It used to be ok to add an extra property, but in TypeScript 1.6 they [changed the behaviour](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks).

If you want this to work in TS 1.6+ then you have to do a type assertion:

```
getX({ x: 0, y: 0, color: "red" } as Point); // no error
```

Comment: Super thank you +1. Well this has to go the documentation. Will help people stepping into typescript.